# Почему пропускает четную запись с помощью Scanner?

Tags: java, scanner

Простая задача, записывать в ArrayList строки, введенные через консоль с помощью Scanner. если ввели end. то больше воодить ничего не надо. у меня почему то второй ввод не учитывается (нет контрольного !!!!!). При этом, когда вывожу список, то отображаются почему-то четные вводы, а не нечетные. Хотя они неотлогировались. сломал мозг. уже по разному модифициоровал код. тоже самое. вот последний вариант

```
package homework1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> info=new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        while ((in.nextLine().equals("end"))==false){
            System.out.println("!!!!!");

            info.add(in.nextLine());

        }

        System.out.println("&&&&&&&&");

        for (String a:info){
            System.out.println(a);
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `nextLine()` не только считывает строку, но и переводит "курсор" на следующую строку. Таким образом, если у вас такой список входных данных:

```
мама
мыла
раму
end
```

то вот здесь: `while ((in.nextLine().equals("end"))==false) {` вы считаете строку `мама`, а вот здесь: `info.add(in.nextLine());` вы работаете уже со строкой `мыла`.

Считайте строку один раз в переменную, а потом уже эту переменную проверяйте и добавляйте в список.